# Can't delete app

Tags: macos

I tried a million different things from different answers around the internet but I couldn't solve this problem. Basically I have deleted a game (Civilization VI) but it's still showing and using precious space on my mac. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's a screenshot. I'll provide more information if requested.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried searching for the word "Civilization" in file names and deleting those that pop up?  Did you use the uninstaller for the game?

Comment: Boot into safe mode and check the space and boot into normal mode again. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262

Comment: @jmh yes, there's nothing left. I can't remember what I used to uninstall it :-(

Comment: @ankii I just did that, also didn't work :(

Comment: what happens if you click on "show in finder" after highlighting this app ?